# How to select elements from a multidimensional array with python : array[:][i][j]?

Tags: python, arrays

In Python, I have a 3 dimensional array `A` :

```
A=np.random.random((3,2,3))

print(A)

Out[6]: [[[0.89565135 0.79502322 0.89015957]
  [0.40303084 0.80496231 0.50278239]]

 [[0.70610822 0.61269108 0.00470925]
  [0.29734101 0.67986295 0.34584381]]

 [[0.71822397 0.99326199 0.40949422]
  [0.97733739 0.38916931 0.91475145]]]
```

I would like to select the first element of each submatrix and to make an array from them `[0.89565135,0.70610822,0.71822397]` so I tried the following formula : `A[:][0][0],A[0][:][0],A[0][0][:]` but they all give me the same result, which is not the one I'm expecting...

```
A[:][0][0]
Out[7]: array([0.89565135, 0.79502322, 0.89015957])

A[0][:][0]
Out[8]: array([0.89565135, 0.79502322, 0.89015957])

A[0][0][:]
Out[9]: array([0.89565135, 0.79502322, 0.89015957])
```

What formula can I use to get the right array and how come the above formula give the same result ?

Comment: Compare `A[:,0,0]` to  `A[0,:,0]` and  `A[0,0,:]`. Still identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows to select for all channel, the first element of the matrix:

```
A[:, 0, 0]
```

`:` references all channels, `0` the first row and `0` the first column.

Output:

```
array([0.89565135,0.70610822,0.71822397])
```

**EDIT:**

If your are working with nested `list`, you can do as follows:

```
[array[0][0]for array in A]
```

This shows one of the benefit of `numpy` array over python `list` as the selection is much more easier (and faster) using `numpy`.

Comment: But still if I write the array directly not as a numpy array :
`A=[[[0.89565135, 0.79502322, 0.89015957], [0.40303084, 0.80496231, 0.50278239]],
 [[0.70610822, 0.61269108, 0.00470925], [0.29734101, 0.67986295, 0.34584381]],
 [[0.71822397, 0.99326199, 0.40949422], [0.97733739, 0.38916931, 0.91475145]]]`
the problem remains. Do you have an idea in that case ?

Comment: I added a solution using nested `list`. However i would advise to perform this operation with `numpy` as it is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea for indexing is a bit flawed here, when you're doing `A[:][0][0]` what you're doing is
`A[:]` would mean basically the whole matrix, out of which you're specifying out the first index using `A[:][0]` which would be

```
[[0.89565135 0.79502322 0.89015957]
  [0.40303084 0.80496231 0.50278239]]
```

out of which you're further specifying the first index `A[:][0][0]` which will give you the first row

```
[0.89565135 0.79502322 0.89015957]
```

Following a similar logic you can see that in your second indexing scheme you're effectively doing the same thing. What you need to do is to do

```
 A[0][0][0]
 A[1][0][0]
 A[2][0][0]
```

which you can write in short hand

```
A[:,0,0]
```